# The app stoped while tring to run ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

When I am touching the button that supose to get me to another Activity, it opens and open it propatly but right before its lunching the list  the app stoped here is the.

What should I do to fix it?

ArrayList code:

```
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    words.add("One");
    words.add("Two");
    words.add("Three");
    words.add("Four");
    words.add("Five");
    words.add("Six");
    words.add("Seven");
    words.add("Eight");
    words.add("Nine");
    words.add("Ten");
    LinearLayout routeView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.routeView);
    int index = 0;
    TextView wordView = new TextView(this);
    wordView.setText(words.get(index));
    routeView.addView(wordView);

    index = index+ 1;

    TextView wordView2 = new TextView(this);
    wordView2.setText(words.get(index));
    routeView.addView(wordView2);
   /*and so on*/
```

> crash log: 08-22 16:35:57.703 30005-30005/com.example.android.miwok
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              Process: com.example.android.miwok, PID: 30005
>                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.android.miwok/com.example.android.miwok.NunbersActivity}:
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 10, size is 10
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
>                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 10, size
>   is 10
>                                                                                  at
>   java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
>                                                                                  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.example.android.miwok.NunbersActivity.onCreate(NunbersActivity.java:98)
>                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6272)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157) 
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356) 
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551) 
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)

Comment: Any error message?

Comment: share your crash log

Comment: I forgot to say, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then only you can get better solution(s)

Comment: unfortanatly the app has stopped

Comment: @Tal the crash log that show in logcat

Comment: it's to long to write

Comment: i added the crush log to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not paste all the code, but the crash log showed that it is a array index out of bound error.

For your case, it's safer to use a **for** loop to avoid misuse of array index.

```
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
words.add("One");
words.add("Two");
words.add("Three");
words.add("Four");
words.add("Five");
words.add("Six");
words.add("Seven");
words.add("Eight");
words.add("Nine");
words.add("Ten");
LinearLayout routeView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.routeView);
for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
    TextView wordView = new TextView(this);
    wordView.setText(words.get(i));
    routeView.addView(wordView);
}
```